# Why $\sup_{\|h\|_{L^1}\leq 1}\int |m(x)|^2|h(x)|dx=\sup_{\|h\|_{L^2}\leq 1}\int |Th(x)|^2dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:L^2\to L^2$ a bounded linear operator defined by $Tg(x)=n(x)g(x)$ where $m\in L^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$.

I don't see why
$$\sup_{\|h\|_{L^1}\leq 1}\int |m(x)|^2|h(x)|dx=\sup_{\|\tilde h\|_{L^2}\leq 1}\int |T\tilde h(x)|^2dx\leq \|T\|_{L^2\to L^2}.$$

The first inequality looks to come from nowhere. For the second, $$\int|T\tilde h|^2=\|Th\|_{L^2}^2$$ and thus $$\sup_{\|h\|_{L^2}\leq 1}\int |Th|^2\leq\sup_{\|h\|_{L^2}\leq 1} \|Th\|_{L^2}^2,$$
but it's not $\sup_{\|h\|_{L^2}\leq 2}\|Th\|_{L^2}$... any idea ?

Comment: For the second, the thing to notice is that the norm in question is an operator norm $\|T\|_{L^2 \to L^2}$.

Comment: @GaryMoon: And so ?

Comment: One typically defines $\|T\|_{\text{op}} = \sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Tv\|$. That definition should explain the second inequality.

Answer (score 1):

For the second inequality, note that the norm in question is $\|T\|_{L^2\to L^2}$, where we can define 
$$\|T\|_{L^2\to L^2} = \sup_{\|\tilde{h}\|_{L^2}\leq1} \|T\tilde{h}\|_{L^2}.$$
For the first inequality, I imagine it's quite a simple move, perhaps something like taking $\tilde{h} = h^\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: but we have $\sup \|Th\|_{L^2}^2$ not $\sup \|Th\|_{L^2}$. How can you pass from the first to the second one ? in other words why $\sup \|Th\|_{L^2}^2\leq \sup \|Th\|_{L^2}$ ?

Comment: The restriction on the $L^2$ norm of $\tilde{h}$ (plus the structure of $T$) should allow for the given comparison.